# How to convert a bigint in AWS timestream DB to timestamp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I want to execute this query:

```
select *  FROM "data-api-timestream-test"."table_test" where time = 1637339664248
```

I get the error:

```
line 1:71: '=' cannot be applied to timestamp, bigint
```

I also tried

```
select *  FROM "data-api-timestream-test"."table_test" where time = cast(1637339664248 as timestamp)
```

I get the error:

```
line 1:73: Cannot cast bigint to timestamp
```

Answer (score 3):

**1. Unix epoch to timestamp**

To convert a unix epoch time to timestamp in Timestream you can use Timestream function `from_milliseconds`:

```sql
from_milliseconds(unixtime_in_millisecond)
```

*In your example:*

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM "data-api-timestream-test"."table_test"
WHERE
    time = from_milliseconds(1637339664248)
```

**2. Timestamp to unix epoch**

For, the other way around - converting a timestamp to milliseconds since unix epoch origin - you can use function `to_milliseconds`:

```sql
to_milliseconds(CURRENT_TIME)
```

*Full example:*

```sql
SELECT 
    time, 
    to_milliseconds(time) AS unixtime,
    from_milliseconds(to_milliseconds(time)) AS unixtime_to_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS time
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these variants, actually they are almost same:

```
select *  FROM "data-api-timestream-test"."table_test" where time = from_iso8601_timestamp('2021-11-19T16:34:24.248Z')
```

or

```
select *  FROM "data-api-timestream-test"."table_test" where time = '2021-11-19 16:34:55.248000000'
```

Just convert your BigInt value to timestamp, of ISO 8601 timestamp in advance